# border for textField in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, field

I have some problem with textField. I have to set border 0 for it dynamically.
i try do this:

```
field.border = 0;
```

and this

```
field..addCls( "border: 0px ;" );
```

but i didn't have any result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify **fieldStyle** property like so :

```
var a = Ext.create("Ext.form.field.Text",{
   fieldLabel:"testField",
   emptyText:"asdasd",
   padding:5,
   renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
   fieldStyle:"border:none 0px black"
});
```

fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad_erdin/jz7ck/)

just like @David Kanarek said...  more snippets, more better.

Answer (score 0):

Try including `border: 0` in the config which creates the field. If you post some more code I can be more specific.